# Null value set to True, but still it violates not-null constraint

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am trying to set the sidebar_id value as null but I get an IntegrityError error:

```
IntegrityError at /admin/qa/howquestion/112/change/
null value in column "sidebar_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (112, <p>prettyprint a JSON file<br></p>, To pretty print a JSON file in Python, you can use the json m...).
```

That's strange because null is set to True already:

```
sidebar = models.ForeignKey(Sidebar, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='qa_sidebars',null=True, blank=True)
```

And I have applied migrations too.

Please note that the error does not occur in development where an SQLite3 database is connected. This only happens in deployment which uses PostGreSQL.

I have ran out of options. I searched everything and still don't understand this. Anyone can help?

**Edit 1:** I just checked migration files to make sure the migration was applied. This file suggests the migration was applied, I *think*:

```
# Generated by Django 3.2 on 2024-03-14 16:48
  
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('marketing', '0001_initial'),
        ('qa', '0022_howquestion_no_code'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='howquestion',
            name='sidebar',
            field=models.ForeignKey(blank=True, null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.SET_NULL, related_name='qa_sidebars', to='marketing.sidebar'),
        ),
    ]
~
```

**Edit 2:**
I run the `showmigrations` command and there is an X next to the migration above:

```
qa
 [X] 0023_alter_howquestion_sidebar
```

So, that migration has already been applied with migrate.

I also just checked the database table directly with  `\d qa_howquestion` found out that `sidebar_id` Nullable attribute is set to `not null`. So, Django shows that the migration which alters the field to allow non nulls has been applied, but that's apparently not the case! How so?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7UO7.png

Comment: Have you confirmed that the migration has applied by reading the migrations table directly in that Postgres database? Depending on how complex your deployment system is, there are probably dozens of reasons you might think the migration is applied but it really has not.

Comment: @BillHuneke I just checked the migration files after your message. I edited the question accordingly. It seems migrations are applied, no?

Comment: I recommend you query the database directly.  Tackling a problem such as yours requires that you find ways to independently verify your assumptions.  Other than SELECTing from the table directly, you could also access it through Django's shell with `from django.db.migrations.recorder import MigrationRecorder` and 
`print(MigrationRecorder.Migration.objects.order_by('-applied').values_list())`

Comment: the file is *created* with `makemigration`, but you should `migrate` to effectively change the database.

Comment: The presence / existence of a migration file does not imply the migration has been run as well. Run [python manage.py showmigrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/django-admin/#showmigrations) and check whether your migration has been run or not.

Comment: I did `showmigrations` and there is an X next to the migration shown in my edited question. So, that migration has already been applied with `migrate`. 

I also just checked the database table directly and yes, the sidebar_id `Nullable` attribute is set to `not null`. 

So, Django shows that the migration has been applied, but that's not the case! How so?

Comment: Can you try `python manage.py migrate YourAppName` syntax.

Comment: Another method is as follows. 1) rename `sidebar` model field to something else. 2) then run null able migration 3) rename again to older field name.

Answer (score -3):

That was an issue moving some python scripts to Linux for me.
They were using winapi for NULL values. In windows you can use NULL if you import the winapi but it's usually a lot less trouble to just use 0 for NULL. If the id field is autoincrement you have to use 0.

Comment: It isn't very obvious (to me, at least) how this answers the OP's question.