# Making changes in the Django models VS. making changes directly on the database vs

Tags: django, database

This question is motivated by [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78162249) I posted yesterday where the migrations I have applied are not altering the database tables.

So, my only solution to do that change is to alter the database directly through SQL commands. Specifically, I want to allow nulls in a particular table field.

Are there any pitfalls I should be aware of before doing that change directly on the PostGreSQL database?

Comment: I posted some methods on your old question's comments. Can you please check.

Answer (score 0):

Django expects the DB to be in line with the models.py files so if you are going to apply changes directly into the database, you may find problems in the future (I certanly did...).

In my case, I manually deleted a UNIQUE restriction, which caused a mismatch between the database schema and the models.py, which caused Django to not let me create nor apply any migrations, nor reset the migrations to zero, until I found out what the issue was and changed the DB back to solve it.

I can't recommend this method, but if you decide to go with it you should definitely take note of any manual changes applied for future reference **so that you know what to undo** if/when Django stops allowing you to apply new migrations. Be specially mindful of any changes to indexes, foreign keys and restrictions like uniques.

However, you'd be better off trying to find out why the migration is not being applied correctly or unapplying the migration and applying it again. You can achieve this by applying the previous-to-last migration.

To reapply the migration, if the migration that causes trouble is the number 0003, you can do:

```
# we go back to the migration previous to the problematic one
python manage.py migrate myapp 0002
```

which will unapply the migration 0003, and then migrate again:

```
python manage.py migrate myapp

# then, check if the migration has been applied
python manage.py showmigrations myapp
```

You could also reset and apply all migrations again.

Other considerations:

- Do the DB credentials you use in Django have enough privileges to make changes to the DB tables? Have those same credentials worked when applying previous migrations?
- Have you tried creating an object with the problematic field as null after the migration to ensure the migration is really not working?
- Are you checking the correct DB? (Happened to me more than once...)

I hope these help you pinpoint the issue.

Whatever you end up doing just keep note of it. I wasted many days trying to fix the mismatch in my backend when it happened to me, and the stress is really not worth it.